# Is it an efficient strategy to deploy collaborative tools like Office 365 only to a subset of employees?

Tags: telecommute, software, collaboration

I work for an industrial company with a lot of business done in back-office (including design, engineering, R&D). The company has decided (and confirmed its decision multiple times) to have a *very* slow rollout for Microsoft 365 collaboration tools, on a 5-year scale, until 2025. The decision aims at saving money on licenses.

*Note: My concern is mostly on the collaborative, online tools of Microsoft 365 (Teams, Tasks, OneDrive), not the regular Microsoft desktop suite).*

Each year, we get a number of licenses that is about 20% of our headcount. And now it appears that we are contemplating the idea of not actually deploying to everyone in the long term, limiting it to people "who really need it". It is argued that the return on investment in "unclear".

All other companies I deal with have deployed Microsoft 365 tools (or similar platform) at full scale, immediately, and sometimes long ago. Is this "a thing" in other companies to stick with the  old, pre-pandemic way of working, to save money on licenses?

I am currently unsure about the attitude I should have. **Should I keep trying to convince the management that the decision is wrong?** Or should I rather accept the situation as it is, try to make the best use of the licenses we have, and hope to be able to prove the value of such collaborative tools in the long term?

Comment: There are other options between license Office365 and leave employees out of the communication loop by not giving them anything.  You could, for example, mandate LibreOffice installations, and give everyone an office suite where nobody pays for licenses.

Answer (score 2):

> not actually deploying to everyone in the long term, limiting it to people **"who really need it"**.

This thing is like saying that only the people who **really need to work** will be allowed to work.

So the better strategy is to let go of the employees which will not do useful work anyway. Not only save licensing money, but also salaries money.

> Are we alone out there?

Not at all. The world is full of such companies and such managers. For some (sad) amusement you might want to look into [thedailywtf.com](http://thedailywtf.com) and [dilbert.com](http://dilbert.com).

> to save money on licenses?

The companies which focus more on saving, rather than investing or cautiously spending, are the companies which are actually going down. They are just fighting to delay the moment of hitting the bottom.

Note: there is a huge difference between "saving" on one side, and "cutting losses" or "not spending uselessly", on the other side. The result might look similar, but the details and the context are very different.

> Is it an efficient strategy to deploy collaborative tools like Office 365 **only to a subset of employees**?

Actually yes. The employees which only hit nails with hammers do not really need Office tools. The personal responsible for cleaning also does not need Office. Examples can continue. One possible exception: the managers of those people might actually need to use Office.

Comment: Imagine that you are an employee that suddenly is asked to review something, but you discover that there isn't a software license, so you now need to discover a way to open the document that was sent to you.  How much would that cost the company (in attempting to borrow someone else's computer, or getting a print out, and then trying to relay your suggestions on paper?)  If you don't want to license Office365, just ditch that overpriced suite, install OpenOffice on everyone's computer and have one of your team support the the free office suite.

Comment: I already have the problem that I do not have the right tools for the job - it is just not about Office. However, the question was not about which are the cheaper alternatives. Unfortunately.

Comment: I misunderstand.  If you have two options, one which requires paid licenses, and another that performs the same operations on the same documents but doesn't require paid licenses, how is using the one that is cheaper not be "the right tool"?  If they provided different functionalities, I could understand, but they are not different functionalities, in this case it's like saying "I can't afford enough brand name soap, so how can I wash all my clothes?"  The answers are "have less clothes or use cheaper, non-brand name soap"

Comment: MS Office has features that powerusers actually use, normal users don't. So you have 3 bad option: 1. everybody get MS Office -> costs money 2. everybody get LibreOffice (it's better than OpenOffice) -> powerusers suffer 3. you mix MS Office and LibreOffice -> breaks whenever the powerusers share something with a normal user. Which happens frequently enough that 1. is often the cheapest alternative.

Comment: @Benjamin Those features include embedding VBA, and preconfigured templates, as well as integration into remote systems, automatic form filling, and other items.  Please don't treat a person who has experience programming against these systems (on both platforms) as someone who doesn't know.  Yes, there will be an adoption cost to migrate, even if they are nearly the same; but, that cost is time and not money.  If you think that paying the license fees is the cheapest alternative, then pay it and stop complaining

Comment: @EdwinBuck: I do not get your point at all. You seem to be an advocate of LibreOffice. I am also open (and I welcome) free software, but the discussion here is different. Also, please note that price is not the only factor to consider when buying anything. Among others, support costs are very important. Compliance to standards is also important. The usability in certain situations can be a decision changer (e.g., functional or passive safety). From my point of view, office tools should be forbidden from engineering projects entirely. There are dedicated tools to help things happen.

Comment: @virolino I advocate that everyone have a word processor, and a spreasheet program.  Some people make the mistake of thinking that only Microsoft Office's suite can handle these items, when there are about 12 different word processors and spreadsheet programs that can handle documents created in Microsoft Office.  So if you can't buy the licenses, then the next best thing is not to say "you can't participate in work if it's in Word or Excel" it's "use this compatible word processor / spreadsheet program.  LibreOffice is only one of many, it doesn't matter which one you use.

Comment: @virolino As for your opinion, it's silly.  Presentations (PowerPoint) are often required to communicate ideas effectively.  Documentation can exist in many forms, one of which is a Word document.  Calculating simple statistics on performance often needs more than a calculator (Excel).  If I, as an engineer, had to work without these tools, I'd find replacements.  If I wasn't allowed to use replacements, I would find a replacement employer.

Comment: *" If I, as an engineer, had to work without these tools, I'd find replacements."*  Well, they are already replacements. And actually, bad replacements. If you did not hear yet about requirements engineering with traceability and statistics, test management tools (with traceability and statistics), bug trackers (statistics included) etc, then it is a pity. An engineer should work with engineer's tools, not with a secretary's tools. And everything I just said should be the norm not only for software development, but for pretty much everything else.

Answer (score 2):

The message the company sends to those on the later half of the deployment rollout is that they don't matter. That is true even if the rollout is done in a few months, it is made worse by it taking years.

What this does is expose the company documents to the dirty internet. If there is a document that employee x has to read, edit, and submit but the software on the company equipment is ancient, the employee will send the file to their home computer, make the edits, and then send it back. Now that company propriety document is sitting on their home PC or the google docs.

> Is this "a thing" in other companies to stick with the old,
> pre-pandemic way of working, to save money on licenses?

For some companies this is the normal way they operate. They look at the cost of licenses, and other tools, and ask employees to use their own tools. I have seen companies limit employees to a single ancient small monitor, instead of spending a few hundred on pair of large monitors. The cost of the hardware they can see, the cost of the inefficiency is hidden.

Comment: since OP also said not everybody gets onedrive, these files will gradually be on more and more filesharing services. So it's not only google docs, but Dropbox and friends too!